# Android: App stops working

Tags: android, bluetooth

inside `OnCreate()`

```
 if (!bAdapter.isEnabled()) {
      Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
      discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,300);
      startActivity(discoverableIntent);
      getPairedDevices();
```

in `getPairedDevices()`

```
private void getPairedDevices() 
{

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

myThread t=new myThread();

t.start();

}


    private class myThread extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                setTextView("hello");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Why does the app gives error after switching on the bluetooth?

Thanks!

Comment: Please format **all** of your code correctly and post the logcat

Comment: I have formatted your code now please provide logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem

```
setTextView("hello");
```

I think its safe to assume that this line updates the `UI` which you are trying to do from a background `Thread` and this can not happen. You should use `runOnUiThread()` where you need to update the `UI` from a background `Thread`.

```
}finally{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            setTextView("hello");
        }
    });
```